# How can I get a warning-free Node.js build?

Tags: node.js, npm, expo

When bootstrapping a new [Expo](https://expo.dev) project with `expo init ...`, I see the following warning (among about a dozen others) right off the bat:

```
warning expo > uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
```

OK, great. I understand the concern. Then, I go over [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid#upgrading-from-uuid3x) and see that, while there are some possible breakages, I went through and verified that none of the calling code seems to run afoul of them. Then, using [Yarn resolutions](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/), I add this to my `package.json`:

```
  "resolutions": {
    "uuid": "7.0.3",
    ...
  }
```

Next, I delete `node_modules` and `yarn.lock`, and `yarn install` again, and now I get *this* warning:

```
warning Resolution field "uuid@7.0.3" is incompatible with requested version "uuid@^3.4.0"
```

So, essentially, I've traded one warning for another. What I really want here is an error **and** warning free build. I'm willing to accept responsibility for the breakage I might cause by pinning "incompatible" versions. Or if I could turn these warnings on/off (one by one) somehow, it'd be suboptimal, but I'd probably be fine with that.

I come from a previous life of developing safety-critical systems in C & C++, where we operated under a doctrine of 'warnings are errors waiting to happen; no warnings allowed ever.' I've noticed from looking at many other Node.js projects that many folks working in this ecosystem seem to just say, "Warnings? YOLO!", and I can see why, TBH. When the problematic dependency is a 7 layer deep, transitive dependency (all 7 of which you didn't write, don't "own", and are unlikely to be able to edit/fix, and 6 of which you didn't even explicitly *ask* for) I can see how it might be easy to say, "Not my problem!" and push onward.

But is it really the case that there's just no hope for a warning free build? I thought `resolutions` would be the solution to this, and it was helpful for one dependency that was a "compatible" version, but I'm driving myself nuts trying to figure out how to simply get a clean build on an effectively empty (i.e. no code of my own) project. There have to be companies/teams out there with similar desires, so I'm assuming there's some solution I'm not aware of. Does anyone have any hot tips?

I've tried:

- `yarn resolutions` (as described)
- `npm-force-resolutions` (seems like an abomination -- it edits your `packages-lock.json`, requires 'double installing')
- `force-resolutions` (which looks like just a newer fork of `npm-force-resolutions`, and has the same issues).
- I've read about NPM v8.3's `overrides` (and it looks promising, TBH), but Expo's cloud building service uses NPM v8.1, so that's off the table until some nebulous moment in the future.

I just can't believe this an unsolvable problem, or that I'm somehow the first person to try to solve it. Thanks!